# DOM. Get value attribute from a given text in option tag

Tags: php, dom, xpath, css-selectors, goutte

I am trying to get the value from the given text, either by a CSS selector or an xpath expression but I don't know whether it's possible to carry this out or not.
This is my HTML:

```
 <select name="product" style="width: 430px">
<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="3181">389-ds-base</option>
<option value="3511">7-Zip</option>
```

Let's say I want to get the value 3511 by giving the text.

The reason I want this is because I want to do webcrawling like this:

```
require_once '/root/PHP/goutte.phar';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://oval.mitre.org/repository/data/search/');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Search')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('product' => '3511'));
$nodeValues = $crawler->filterXPath('//td[@nowrap][position()>4]/a')->each(function ($node) {
    return $node->text();
});
```

And I don't want to pass the number 3511 as an argument but the text.

Hope I made myself clear, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath expression `string(//option[.="7-Zip"]/@value)` will find any `<option>` element whose text content equals "7-Zip" and return its *value* attribute as a string.

Comment: You mean string as a PHP function which recieves the xpath `//option[.="7-Zip"]/@value` as a parameter¿?

Answer (score 3):

References:

1. [Symfony DomCrawler Component Documentation - Accessing DomCrawler Node Values](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#accessing-node-values)
2. [DomCrawler API Reference - filterXPath() Method](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_filterXPath)
3. [DomCrawler API Reference - extract() method](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_extract)
4. [Github Code View - DomCrawler::filter()](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler/blob/master/Crawler.php#L667)
5. [DOMXPath::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

To begin with, I would refer you to the fact that the DomCrawler::filter() and DomCrawler::filterXPath() methods are wrappers around the DomCrawler::filterRelativeXPath() private method.

Glancing at the API reference for both the filter() and filterXPath() methods you will notice that both will return a DomCrawler instance; as viewable from within the filterRelativeXPath() method.  The filterRelativeXPath() method in turn this uses PHP's XPath::query() method.

The XPath expression provided by Paul, while technically correct, will not work for you with the context of the Symfony DomCrawler.  In fact if you were to do:

```
$value = $crawler->filterXPath('string(//option[.="7-Zip"]/@value)');
```

you would probably get an error or warning from DOMXPath::query()

When using the Symfony DomCrawler component, you would have to do something like:

```
$value = $crawler->filterXPath('//option[.="7-Zip"]/') // get the node
                 ->extract(['value'])[0];              // extract the value attribute and then associate the first element of the resulting array to $value
```